# How to pass single quote inside a '<%# %>' quantifier

Tags: javascript, binding, alert, html-escape-characters

I have a neat Javascript function that checks the validity of a bound field. However, I want to place an ELSE {} in the line to send an alert() function call and display an error.

This is what works for me...

```
onClick='<%# "if(chkMobile(\"" + Eval("pssPhone").ToString() + "\")) { highlightRow(this); }" %>'
```

This does not work for me ...

```
onClick='<%# "if(chkMobile(\"" + Eval("pssPhone").ToString() + "\")) { highlightRow(this); } else { alert(&apos;Invalid mobile phone number&apos;); }" %>'
```

I've tried to escape the single quotes with `\'`, `\\\'`, `\'''`, and even `'` on its own. I always get badly formed errors.

The `&apos;` does not work either, but at least I don't get any errors. In fact with the `&apos;` the highlightRow() doesn't fire which is worse!

I've also tried `&quot;` with no luck.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you use any template engine you should see the escape character or chain it use.

Comment: I was looking for one just now, but I could not find any. Got a link please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**
I took a punt and decided to inject double-quotes and it works like a charm!

```
onClick='<%# "if(chkMobile(\"" + Eval("pssPhone").ToString() + "\")) { highlightRow(this); } else { alert(\"" + "Invalid mobile phone number" + "\"); }" %>'
```